# Linq to Nhibernate strange behaviour

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, conform

I have a table fill query, which have to get all references entities.

I have client:

```
public class Client 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Address CurrentAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Address

```
public class Address 
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }      
   public virtual string City { get; set; }
   public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

and DB diagram:

[image]

I want get all users Addresses by Linq to Nhibernate:

```
ClientRepository.Where(x => x.Id == clientId).SelectMany(c => c.Addresses ).Where(x => x.Address1.Contains("Comp")).ToList();
```

But I got this query:

```
SELECT TOP (20 /* @p0 */) Id31_,
                 Address2_31_,
                 Address3_31_,
                 City31_,                
                 ZipCode31_
FROM   (select address2_.Id                                    as Id31_,
               address2_.Address1                              as Address2_31_,
               address2_.Address2                              as Address3_31_,
               address2_.City                                  as City31_,               
               address2_.ZipCode                               as ZipCode31_,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY address2_.Address1) as __hibernate_sort_row
        from   CLIENTS client0_
               inner join AddressToClient addresshis1_
                 on client0_.Id = addresshis1_.ClientId
               inner join ADDRESSES address2_
                 on addresshis1_.AddressId = address2_.Id
        where  address2_.Id = 2 /* @p1 */) as query
WHERE  query.__hibernate_sort_row > 0 /* @p2 */
ORDER  BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

EDITED
My repository:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the repository query.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The repository query.</value>
protected override IQueryable<Client> RepositoryQuery
{
   get
   {
     return Session.Query<Client>();
   }
}
```

Where query filters by `id = address2_.Id` not client id.

Why search appears by address Id not client?

Comment: Show us your `ClientRepository`. It's probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I have added Client Repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing one of your two "x" variable names to something different. There is a bug in the current NHibernate release version that could cause this.